# what is the meaning of the word "regression" in "linear regression"?

Tags: regression, history

I understand the algorithm of linear regression, how it works and what it accomplishes, and how to apply it in ML

but what is the meaning of the word "regression" itself in that context? what's the history or etymology in using that word?

or put slightly differently, how did the word 'regression' came to mean *learn a formula from independent variables to an outcome variable*? the word itself seems to describe the concept rather poorly

Comment: Related (duplicate?): [Why are regression problems called “regression” problems?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/11087)